# Laravel 4 - Enumerating @foreach

Tags: for-loop, foreach, laravel-4

I want to enumerate some content in a @foreach. I need something like:

```
1 - First data
2 - Second data
  ...
```

I've displayed the data using a @foreach, but I need to enumerate it. I've tried with @for, combining with @foreach, but it hasn't worked for my... Does anybody know how to do it?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are you iterating through regular or associative array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
@foreach ($collection as $item)
    <p>{{ $i }} - {{ $item->property }}</p>
    <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array keys are not the index you want to enumerate, you can do this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
    {{ $i }} - {{ $data[$i]->field }}
@endfor
```

If you can use the array key for enumeration, you can do this:

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }} - {{ $value->field }}
@endforeach
```